# How to filter an array in vue by name and list

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, vuejs2, computed-properties

I have an array with a computed property to filter by name. I want to be able to filter by tags but return categories.name if a tag is found as well. For example if I type lunch in the input I want it to return Restaurant and populate the list just with Restaurant if empty the full list.

```
 <input type="text" v-model="this.search">
 <ul>
   <li v-for="(category, index) in filter">
   {{category}}
   </li>
 </ul> 

data: {
    search: '',
    categories : [
      {
        name: "Restaurants",
        tags: ["Restaurants", "Lunch", "Dinner"]
      },
        {
        name: "Barber",
        tags: ["Hair", "Hair Cut", "Shave"]
    }
    ]
  },
computed: {
filter(){
 return this.mainCat.filter((doc) => {
     return doc.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
filteredData() {
 this.categories.filter(c => {
   if(c.tags.includes(this.search)) {
     return c
   }
 })
}
```

Add that one in your computed property. In your v-for loop just target name if you want to return only the name.

Comment: Thank You is there anyway to show a partial match for example when I use .match it starts showing partial matches once I start typing in the input box.

Comment: @AlexisFortuño, It will start filtering when you start typing. I think its the best approach to filter the data.